# When is onNothingSelected method implemented?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Can anyone please explain me implementation of onNothingSelected() of Spinner with an Example

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    ...

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Selected Item is -"+ (TextView)view.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
Toast.makeText(this,"nothing is selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

Comment: From the android documentation
"Callback method to be invoked when the selection disappears from this view. The selection can disappear for instance when touch is activated or when the adapter becomes empty."

Answer (score 1):

onNothingSelected is a Callback method to be invoked when the selection disappears from this view. The selection can disappear for instance when touch is activated or when the adapter becomes empty.
I think it pretty much answers your question. So if your spinner disappear for other reason except selecting the item then onNothingSelected will be called. So as it's name tells it is needed to find out when nothing is selected